# Issues while converting from direct JMS to JNDI

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ibm-mq, jndi

The below Java code is reading host, post, QueueManagerName and channel values directly from properties file. How do I change this to read JNDI values from websphere application server. In properties we have only JNDI name value available.

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQC;
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import java.util.Hashtable;
public class MQConnection {
  private String host;
  private String port;
  private String queueManagerName;
  private String channel;
  public MQConnection() {
  }
  MQQueueManager queueManager;
  public void init() {
      try {
        Hashtable mqEnvProperties = new Hashtable();
        if (host != null) {
          mqEnvProperties.put(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, host);
        }
        if (port != null) {
            Integer portInt = Integer.valueOf(port); 
          mqEnvProperties.put(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY,portInt);
        }
        if (channel != null) {
          mqEnvProperties.put(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY,channel);
        }
        if (queueManager != null && queueManager.isConnected() == true) {
          queueManager.disconnect();
        }
        queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, mqEnvProperties);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  public String getChannel() {
    return channel;
  }
  public String getHost() {
    return host;
  }
  public String getPort() {
    return port;
  }
  public MQQueueManager getQueueManager() {
    if (queueManager == null || queueManager.isConnected() == false) {
        init();
    }
    return queueManager;
  }
  public String getQueueManagerName() {
    return queueManagerName;
  }
  public void setChannel(String channel) {
    this.channel = channel;
  }
  public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
  }
  public void setPort(String port) {
    this.port = port;
  }
  public void setQueueManagerName(String queueManagerName) {
    this.queueManagerName = queueManagerName;
  }

  public void finalize(){
     if (this.queueManager!=null){
        try {
          this.queueManager.disconnect();
          this.queueManager=null;
        } catch (MQException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
     }
}
```

I have tried something like

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
// lookup the queue connection factory
ConnectionFactory connFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
```

Comment: That's what you should try all right. Your question doesn't state whether it worked or not, which isn't usefu, and, if it didn't work, what the symptoms were. The actual lookup name depends entirely on how your server is configured. We can't tell you.

Comment: The code you show is using IBM MQ classes for Java API.  To use JNDI you would need code using IBM MQ classes for JMS.  These are very different APIs.